# PowerPoint Rehearse Timings with Use Presenter View Checked

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I am trying to rehearse a presentation and have been dismayed to discover that when trying to use *Rehearse Timings* I do not get a *Presenter View*. When just doing slideshow I do but not when attempting to rehearse. This is annoying because I have notes on my slides that I intend to use to jog me while giving the presentation. Is there someway to get *Rehearse Timings* to work in such a way that it actually lets you rehearse?

Comment: The same problem exists in PowerPoint 2013. [I have reported it and Microsoft is working on it.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_winother/no-presenter-view-option-when-recording/66d95e16-e5d9-4aab-adbf-e40e4725ed68?page=1)

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac using Power Point for Mac V15.33 if you go to set up **Slide Show** - **set up slides**, select browsed by individual (window), then select **Slide Show** - **Rehearse timings** it will display the presenter mode with slide and notes.

This works well to practice to see the slides and notes.  You might not have to say browse by individual (window) but that's the way I do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows 7 on a multihead-capable computer (such as your laptop), it will happily pretend that there is a second monitor even if none is plugged in. Then you can turn on Presenter Mode, tell PowerPoint to present on the second monitor, and it's none the wiser that the presentation isn't actually visible and you're only watching the presenter mode.

From the directions at [the PPT FAQ](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01041.htm):

- "Extend" to second monitor with Win-P
- Turn on presenter mode, 2nd monitor
- Rehearse!

Comment: This solution doesn't allow recording the time spent on each slide, which is what the OP is was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? This talks about adding notes in reherse mode http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/mac-powerpoint-help/rehearse-and-set-slide-timings-HA102928508.aspx?CTT=1

Answer (score 0):

Go in **Slides** menu and select **Rehearse Timings**.

If it is not working, then select **Slide Options**, inside the **Slide** menu and see the **Show slide without timing** checkbox.

If it is checked, then uncheck this option, and then record again **Rehearse Timings** and then finally play.

Answer (score -1):

In powerpoint 19, on PC (Windows 10) if you use Alt-F5 to start the presentation, it will show presenter view on screen.  Not sure if this applies to earlier versions.